# Can any one explain this strange behavior about Array sort？

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a array like this

`a = [0, "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", -0.2, -0.05, 0.25, 0.47, 0.875]`.

notice that there are some '-' in this array and only this string appears and the left are numbers.

now I apply sort on this array, just like

```js
a = [0, "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", -0.2, -0.05, 0.25, 0.47, 0.875];
console.log(a.sort((a, b) => (+a || -Infinity) - (+b || -Infinity)));
```

or

```js
a = [0, "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", -0.2, -0.05, 0.25, 0.47, 0.875];
console.log(a.sort((a, b) => (+b || -Infinity) - (+a || -Infinity)));
```

The results I tried are like this

[image]

so the question is.
why desc order works fine but asc order don't?

Comment: `0` and `NaN` are both falsy, so `(+a || -Infinity)` is not the right approach.

Comment: What is the expected result? None of these arrays are sorted intuitively.

Comment: @sebastian-simon you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrays `[0, "-"]` and `["-", 0]`, while different, are both correctly 'sorted' according to the sorting rules you've defined.

Understand that the javascript `sort` method is not a stable sort. If there are multiple equivalent items in the list you are sorting, these equivalent items will be grouped together. However, within each of these groups the order is undefined.

The comparison function you are using defines `0` and '-' as being equivalent.

`+0` is falsey, so therefore `+0 || -Infinity` will return `-Infinity`.

`+"-"` resolves to `NaN`, which is also falsey, so therefore `+"-" || -Infinity` will return `-Infinity`.

The fact that the `0` happens to come before the `-` when you sort descending is just an implementation detail. Try it on a different javascript engine or try it again after the next Chrome update, and you may get a different result, which will nonetheless still be correct.

---

If you want the 0 to be treated like a number (getting a sorted result of `['-', -0.2, -0.05, 0, 0.25, 0.48, 0.875]`) then you could use this:

```
a.sort(
    (l,r ) => 
        (typeof(l) === 'number' ? l : -Infinity) -
        (typeof(r) === 'number' ? r : -Infinity)
);
```

Comment: As of ES10 (which was finalized a month ago), Array#sort is required to be stable. Of course it will take some time for that to be reliable, especially in browsers.